# maximum absolute column sum (column norm) of a matrix and its largest eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-norms

Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. How to prove the following statement?
$$||A||_{L_1}\leq \sqrt{n}\sigma_{\max}(A),$$
where $||A||_{L_1} = \max_{i\in\{1,...,m\}}||\mbox{col}_i(A)||_1$ and $\sigma_{\max}(A)$ is the largest singular value of $A$.

This conclusion is the Fact 9.8.12 xiv) on Page 573 from the book *Matrix Mathematics Theory, Facts, and Formulas* (Second Edition) by Dennis S. Bernstein. (I checked the reference therein but didn't get any clue.)

Comment: What is your question?  You never really ask one.

Comment: @amWhy I've just updated it. My question is how to prove this inequality.

Comment: Hint: All norms are equivalent up to a constant factor.  First show a bound for the $L_2$ norm.  Note that $L_2$ is also called the "spectral norm."  Then figure out the constant factor required to transfer this over to $L_1$.

Comment: Also, note that for any (square) $B$ and any matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ subordinate with respect to some vector norm, we have $\rho(B)\leq\|B\|$. Hence, even though it does not contradict or prove anything about the original question, it hints that the statement is false from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm in question is conventionally denoted by $\|\cdot\|_1$. The inequality as it stands does not make sense, because the eigenvalues of $A$ can be non-real and there isn't any "maximum" eigenvalue in general, but I suppose that by $\lambda_\max(A)$ you mean the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ of $A$.

At any rate, the inequality is false. E.g.
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}\right\|_1=2>\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}\rho(A).
$$
The inequality can be corrected by requiring that $A$ is normal, or more generally, by changing $\rho(A)$ to $\|A\|_2$, the induced $2$-norm (= the largest singular value) of $A$:
\begin{aligned}
\|A\|_1
&=\max_{j=1,2,\ldots,n}\|Ae_j\|_1\\
&\le\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_1\\
&=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\langle|Ax|,e\rangle\\
&\le\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|\,|Ax|\,\|_2\|e\|_2\\
&=\sqrt{n}\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2\\
&=\sqrt{n}\|A\|_2.
\end{aligned}

Comment: You are right -- I misunderstood the notation in the book. I've corrected the question.

Comment: Does $|Ax|$ mean taking the absolute value of every element in the vector $Ax$? Does $e$ denote a vector filled with 1's?

Comment: @Hepdrey Yes and yes.